# How to use more than one URL parameter in sapper/svelte

Tags: svelte, sapper

I just started learning svelte. After reading some of sapper documentation i saw that sapper use file names and folder structure for routing and if i want something like /blog/:article its possible create a folder with 'blog' name and file '[slug].svelte' inside, how i can construct more complex routes? Example: /blog/:article/comments/:commentId

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`src/routes/blog/[article]/comments/[commentId].svelte`

or

`src/routes/blog/[article]/comments/[commentId]/index.svelte`